# How do i create Azure Web App Custom Domain in C#

Tags: c#, azure, web-applications

I have a website that allows multiple tenants each with their own database. I am trying to automate the process of creating a new tenant. This consists of...

1. Create a CNAME record in DNS
2. Create a Custom Domain in the Web App
3. Create the database

I am stuck on point 2.

Currently, my code is ...

```
    
   const string DNS_RESOURCE_GROUP = "myResources";
   const string DNS_NAME = "myDomain.com.au";
   const string DNS_CNAME = "myWebApp.azurewebsites.net";
   const string WEBAPP_RESOURCE_GROUP = "myWebApp_group";
   const string WEBAPP_SERVICE_PLAN = "myWebAppServicePlan";

async Task CreateUpdateWebApp(SubscriptionResource subscription) {
        string rgName = WEBAPP_RESOURCE_GROUP;
        ResourceGroupResource resourceGroup = await subscription.GetResourceGroups().GetAsync(rgName);
        AppServicePlanResource app = await resourceGroup.GetAppServicePlanAsync(WEBAPP_SERVICE_PLAN);
        foreach (var site in app.GetWebApps()) {
            var hostname = $"{details.TenantKey.ToLower()}.{DNS_NAME}";
            if (site.DefaultHostName == DNS_CNAME) {
                HostNameSslState state = new HostNameSslState()
                    {
                        HostType = AppServiceHostType.Standard,
                        Name = $"{hostname}",
                        SslState = HostNameBindingSslState.SniEnabled,

                    };
                site.HostNameSslStates.Add(state);
            }
        }
        AppServicePlanCollection plans = resourceGroup.GetAppServicePlans();
        plans.CreateOrUpdate(WaitUntil.Completed, WEBAPP_SERVICE_PLAN, app.Data);
    }
```

This code compiles & executes but the web app is not updated.

Comment: Exactly which Azure client lib or SDK are you using? It looks like you're using the older legacy NuGet package...

Comment: Assuming that you're using the legacy NuGet package, you also need to use `EnabledHostNames`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.websites.models.site.enabledhostnames?view=azure-dotnet-legacy

Comment: I am using Azure.ResourceManager.AppService. It is certainly not marked as legacy on Nuget.